# I am trying to use a shell script that will contain "awk" to run against a file

Tags: regex, linux, shell, ubuntu

```
read -p "Enter the name for the dealer you are searching for: " dealer
read -p "Enter the time of day you are checking for this dealer: " time
echo "$time $dealer" | awk '/$1/'
```

so this is what I have so far. From what I've learned so far, this will store the user's entered values in `dealer` and `time`.

What I am trying to do next is `echo` that input against a series of commands to see if a file contains those inputs.

For example roulette dealer "Billy" works at "05 AM" every other day. To see if the data from a given date contains his work log, I would run this script.

```
./script
```

runs the file:

> Enter the name for the dealer you are searching for: Billy
>
> Enter the time of day you are checking for this dealer: 05

Now this is where I'm lookiung for a solution. Do I run the script against a file when I call the script? Do I have the user input the file as a third parameter and then have that as a value inside of the script?

If I have learned correctly then the dealer would be stored as arg1 and be accessed by $1, time $2.

So would I run: `awk '1$.2$' file`?

meaning that anything can be between them but if a line does contain the name and time then it is what I am searching for.

> 05:00:00 AM   Katey Bean  Billy Jones Evalyn Howell

This is a desired output for my script, I understand that the time is first in line, so I would make adjustments accordingly, but I am trying to get a step further.

Comment: Interactive prompts are usually a bad idea. Make the script accept the parameters as command-line arguments instead. This makes it a lot easier to build new scripts around this one, and the user can use the shell's history, completion, variables, and other facilities to run the script repeatedly over a range of inputs etc.

Answer (score 0):

After reading in your input for the dealer and time from standard input, you can run `awk` with the following regex:

```
"^$time.*$dealer"
```

to match the lines in the file. (You may need to adapt it to fit your needs, though it should be enough as a starting point).

As for the file itself, `awk` can read from standard input, so you could redirect the file to the script, like this:

```
./script < data.txt
```

and run `awk` like this:

```
awk -v re="^$time.*$dealer" '$0 ~ re { print $0 }'
```

so that `awk` will read the file contents from standard input.

Or, you can supply the filename as an argument, like this:

```
./script data.txt
```

and run `awk` like this:

```
awk -v re="^$time.*$dealer" '$0 ~ re { print $0 }' "$1"
```

where `$1` is the filename.

You could also use the equivalent call to `grep` (which is more succinct in this case!):

```
grep "^$time.*$dealer" "$1"
```